# dql_filter on EasyAdminBundle

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm asking this question here because I didn't see a solution for this in the official Bundle page.

I'm trying to filter the results for a concrete Entity. In the entity I have a boolean column "active", and I want to perform a filter to show only the rows with this field equals to true...

In the docs I found a method to filter this entities:
https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/pull/986

But I don't know when it will be implemented or updated :(

Anyone has a solution for this? Because the only solution that I have for this is to create two entities, one for `active = true` and other for `active = false`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case :

Client: 
            class: AppBundle\Entity\Company

```
        list:
            dql_filter: 'entity.isclient=1'
            title: 'Clients'
```

BUT BE CAREFULL TO USE THE LATEST VERSION; in github you ll find a post as i had the same problem; it was linked to my version of the bundle...